# writeSatisfiedStatus in mapInfo element in SCORM 2004 3rd edition

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

If writeSatisfiedStatus is true for an objective, in this case, which sections of tracking model are copied from local objective to shared global objective?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Answer: `satisfied status` and `Objective Progress Status`. Satisfied Status is determined by the LMS based on the value of `success status` which is set by the SCO. If the success status is set to "unknown", satisfied status is set to null. If success status is set to "passed", satisfied status is set to true. If success status is set to "failed", satisfied status is set to false.

Comment: No, I don't mean Mapping from Run-Time Environment data model to Tracking Model, I mean Tracking Model of local objective to Tracking Model of global objective.

Comment: The answer is the same: satisfied status which is connected to success status of the runtime data model.